# No Matching Provisional Profile when I try to Submit my App to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have a problem when I try to submit my app to the App Store with Xcode 6.

This is the 
[Message](http://tinypic.com/r/xeeii1/8)

I have the Provisioning Profile to the App Store, Submit Certificate, and App`s ID and I distribute my app correctly via TestFlight. And the status in iTunes Connect is **waiting for upload**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is not yet accepting apps built with Xcode 6. You must build it with Xcode 5 or wait for Xcode 6 to come out of beta. From the 'Read Me Before Downloading' section:

> New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with release versions of Xcode 5. Do not submit apps built with beta software, as beta versions are for development and testing only.

Comment: Thanks @skladek... And I can try submit the app thought Application Loader?

Comment: @jghg02, no idea, I haven't tried anything with Xcode 6. Given that it has the potential to use API that are only available on the beta version of the OS, it may not be allowed. If you do go this route, make sure you thoroughly test against iOS 7.